# Spring Batch step write_count less than read_count and filter and skip counts are all zero

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring

We are facing a situation in Spring Batch that step write_count sometimes is less than read_count and filter_count and read_skip_count, process_skip_count and write_skip_count are all zero while the job has been completed successfully with no exception.
We are still investigating but wished to know how can this happen and what can cause that?
Just to add we have 2 different writers for this step and we use classifier to switch between them under some conditions.
Here is the step configuration code:

```
    public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("jobName")
        .<InputTransaction, OutputTransaction>chunk(500)
        .reader(itemReader)
        .processor(itemProcessor)
        .writer(classifierCompositeItemWriter())
        .faultTolerant()
        .skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        .skip(RuntimeException.class)
        .listener(adjustTransactionItemWriter)
        .listener(adjustTransactionItemLogFileWriter)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: That should not be the case. It is possible that the write_count is less than read_count, but in that case the difference should be taken into account in the filter count or skip count. If you share an example that reproduces the issue, I can try to debug the case.

Comment: But it's like that unfortunately and we could not reproduce it in dev environment yet, I will let you know as soon as we could get there, Thanks 
a lot  @MahmoudBenHassine